# How can i debug the query building my table

Tags: php, mysql, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I'm using [jQuery DataTables Editor](https://editor.datatables.net/) with [PHP library](https://editor.datatables.net/manual/php/) and I want to see the final query that is used to build my table. I looked in the following files:

- Editor-PHP-1.5.6/php/Database/Driver/Mysql/Result.php
- Editor-PHP-1.5.6/php/Database/Driver/Mysql/Query.php

and I saw many functions calling each other like "ping-pong" and couldn't find the way to see the final query.

I want to check my joins in the query. Where can i find it?

Comment: mysql general query log, if it's enabled?

Comment: Yes i can see all the queries, its good but its its not the final query, but thats help a lot thanks dude :)

Comment: @sortof the queries you see in general query log ARE the final queries. Whatever is logged there is the real query that ran on the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this is old, and is referring to Editor 1.5, but since Editor 1.6 you can simply add `->debug(true)` into the server's scripts. For more information, see the release notes for 1.6 : https://editor.datatables.net/download/1.6.0 .

Comment: Note that you have to set `->debug(true)` BEFORE `->process()`, or you won't get anything